Drama about a writer from a fishing town
I'm looking for what I believe to be a made for TV movie, perhaps Lifetime. It is about a man who is an aspiring writer from a small New England fishing town pitching his book to a female agent in New York City. They have a romantic connection, but during the course of the movie we find out that he had a wife. She was a doctor who moved to the small town when she developed a health problem. The writer was the handyman in town and they met when he was called to work on her house. 
In the middle of the movie, the man sends the agent a journal which was written by the wife to his child. Eventually, we learn that both of them are deceased, and they died when she had a seizure or some kind of episode and drove off the road. The man that the dead wife describes in her journal is vibrant and romantic, but the writer that the agent knows is mournfully macabre.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Welcome to Movies & TV! When did you see this? How old was it? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors?

Suzanne's Diary for Nicholas (2005) aired on CBS and starred by Christina Applegate.

Kate Wilkinson is a book editor who receives a copy of the diary of Dr. Suzanne Bedford, started in 2003 for her then unborn son Nicholas. Suzanne is a busy Boston physician who discovers she has heart problems. Because having a baby would risk her health, Suzanne ends up breaking up with her boyfriend who wanted children, and also moves to a less stressful island community to take over a general practice. Among her neighbors is the quirky Melanie, who advises her that the house where Suzanne lives and works needs fixing up. Melanie refers her to a man who calls himself Picasso, a Brown graduate who gave up the corporate life working for his father in order to become a writer. Soon the relationship between Suzanne and her handyman becomes more than just friendship.


